# How does the default operator= works in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

I've had some hard times trying to understand how the default copy constructor and the default operator= work in C++.

In the following program, I don't see why the last line `c0 = b2; cout <<endl;` prints out `32944` .

-Does the operator= call the copy constructor if defined ? if not how does it behave ? in this case it seems that b0 when assingned to c0 used the copy constructor:

`C(const B& x) : B(x), a(1){z=0; cout <<"9";}`

-How did the statement `c0 = b2;` use the operator= of the class A (the 44 at the end of the result)?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
  public:
   A(){x=0; cout << "1";}
   A(int t) {x=t; cout << "2";}
   A(const A& a) {x=a.x; cout << "3";}
   const A& operator=(const A& a) {x=a.x; cout << "4"; return *this;}
  protected:
int x;
};

class B{
  public:
   B(const A& a=A()) : y(a) { cout << "5";}
   B(const A& b, int u){y=b; k=u; cout << "6";}
  protected:
   A y; int k;
};

class C : public B{
  public:
   C(int t=1) {z=t; cout <<"7"; }
   C(A x) : B(x) {z=0; cout <<"8";}
   C(const B& x) : B(x), a(1){z=0; cout <<"9";}
  protected:
   A a; int z;
};

int main(){
   B b2; cout << endl;
   C c0; cout <<endl;
   c0 = b2; cout <<endl;

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The default copy-assignment operator basically does a memberwise assignment. All members of `c0` are being assigned from their respective member of the temporary object created by `C(b2)`.

Comment: There is no operator to assign a `B` to a `C`. But `C` has an implicit constructor from `B` ("9"), so the assignment `c0 = b2` calls this implicit constructor and then uses the default copy assignment of `C`. The default copy assignment copies both `A` members of `C`, which explains the "44" at the end of the output.

Comment: @pschill why does it invoke 9 before the 44. it should copy the element than print the 9

Comment: @M. Iduoad As I said it first calls the constructor which prints the 9. Then it assigns the newly constructed object to c2, which prints 44. You could use a debugger and step through all function calls, then it becomes clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`c0 = b2` prints out 32944 correctly.

1. `c0 = b2` calls `c0 = C(b2)`, `y.operator=` (4) and `a.operator=` (4)
2. `C(b2)` calls `B(b2)`, `A(1)` (2) and `cout << 9` (9)
3. `B(b2)` calls `A(b2)`
4. `A(b2)` calls `cout << 3` (3)

From down to up: 3 2 9 4 and your final 4.

Comment: Why does `c0 = C(b2)` call operator= ?

Comment: @M.Iduoad `C` has member `A a`, and `B` has member `A y`.